# Storm topology worker dies after throwing AvroRuntimeException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a scenario where my first bolt of the topology is deserializing a message from Kafka topic based on an Avro schema, the deserialization working fine for messages that follow the correct schema and throws an AvroRuntimeException when the message is just anything else that couldn't be deserialized, Although I am catching the exception and acknowledging the tuple, I get worker died error, is it something related to the storm configuration?

```
@Override
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        bytes = getBinaryFieldFromTuple(input);
        if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(bytes)) {
            log.error("Received empty byte[] - skipping.");
            return;
        }
        Message<E> message = getMessageDecoder().decode(bytes);
        E payload = message.getPayload();
        emit(input, getValuesToEmit(payload, message.getHeaders()));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error while deserializing: {}", bytes, ex);
    } finally {
        ack(input);
    }
}
```

I couldn't see a specific reason for that.

Comment: Are you implementing `BaseRichBolt` or `BaseBasicBolt` and can you also add exact error here.

Comment: @Saurabh I am implementing IRichBolt, and I couldn't provide the detailed error because it doesn't happen frequently.

Comment: If your bytes variable is null, will that cause exception in this statement: `log.error("Error while deserializing: {}", bytes, ex);`

Comment: @Saurabh it gave me NullPointerException: null and also I found something in the logs after the exception was thrown.

38022 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.nimbus - Shutting down master
I am going to try it on another environment other than my local test environment and I'll see the results.

Thanks (Y)